# Symmetries of the square lattice

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, crystals, lattice-model

According to the literature, the square lattice has $C_{4v}$ symmetry. This point group does not contain inversion. However, the square lattice is obviously inversion-symmetric.

Is this because inversion can be constructed by composing two mirror operations?

Answer (score 1):

Your source is being sloppy with notation.  The two-dimensional square lattice has a two-dimensional symmetry point group isomorphic to $C_{4v}$.  However, $C_{4v}$ is really only supposed to be used to refer to subgroups of the three-dimensional point group $O(3)$ of orthogonal transformations.  The three-dimensional point group of the square lattice is $D_{4h}$, which does contain an inversion.  However, if you are neglecting everything in the third dimension (transverse to the surface), the distinction is not important.